# How can I design/test an Angular component without running the entire app?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Is there any way to load an angular component in isolation for design & testing purposes? I am attempting to redesign some components for a fairly complex angular app (it was started in angular2-rc and although it has been updated it's still following some bad design patterns - mostly due to work previously done by inexperienced devs on unreasonably tight deadlines, needless to say we are now developing this in-house). This makes it difficult to access certain nested components.

Currently my workflow for designing and testing a component is as follows:

1. Run the backend app (because of authentication checks etc. - the app is entirely private so needs a valid login to access anything)
2. Run the angular app (`ng serve` handles this and will obviously auto reload on change)
3. Log in to app
4. Navigate back to the relevant page (due to the login redirect taking me away from the page I was on)
5. Fill in the required data on the page to get to the point where my new component would show in a normal use case
6. Design/test/etc my new component, making any necessary changes
7. `if (!done) { goto 2; } else { return; }`

This seems excessive for designing a single component. There must be a better way to simply load my component directly for design and testing purposes. Ideally I would like my workflow to be something along the lines of:

1. Load the angular component directly instead of having to run the entire app (preferably with a way to mock any necessary inputs, services, etc)
2. Design and test component to ensure desired layout, style, functionality, ux, etc - making any changes as necessary
3. `if (!done) { goto 1; } else { goto 4; }`
4. Integrate component into app

Is what I'm looking for even possible? Surely I'm not the first person to run into this problem - UI frameworks are the first come to mind given how they provide a library of generic components to drop in wherever necessary.

Am I missing something? Or is the only way to do this just to create a simple mocked test app and drop the in-dev components there for quick and easy access?

### Update

To clarify, I'm specifically trying to rapidly & iteratively design this component from a mostly visual/rendering perspective. I need to ensure cross-browser consistency, responsiveness at different screen resolutions, elements not overlapping incorrectly or rendering offscreen, colors/fonts/sizes/positions are appropriate in the context of the component (eg. `<h3>` is too big and looks out of place, lets try `<h4>` instead and see how that looks) etc. where the component has nested components which need to be displayed.

I tagged the question with `html` & `css` intentionally - not because those are the languages the component uses, but because those are the aspects of the component I am trying to test.

Thanks to those who have helpfully pasted a link to the docs (which, yes I have read) explaining how to unit test the component and briefly describing how to test certain rendering conditions based on the code (applied classes, attributes, styles etc). What I was unfortunately unable to find in there are tests such as:

- `expect(myComponent).toDisplayIdenticallyAcross(browser.Chrome, browser.Firefox, browser.Edge, browser.Safari);`
- `expect(myLabel.color).toContrastWellWith(myComponent.backgroundColor);`
- `expect(myNestedComponent).toRenderEntirelyOnScreenWithoutOverlapping(true);`

That is to be expected as these are more subjective things which can really only be tested by looking at them and making minor tweaks as necessary. I'm simply trying to find a simpler way to do that without having to reload the entire app a minimum of three times just to see whether having my heading left, center or right aligned looks better.

Comment: have you read the docs? https://angular.io/guide/testing as a side note, you sound like a guy that just interviewed me this morning - he's also dealing with a badly designed angular app

Comment: I have, but the don't really go into what I'm trying to achieve. Updated question to clarify. Also I'm not the guy who interviewed you, but I doubt lead devs inheriting a poorly designed angular app (without any unit testing, ughh...) is that uncommon. Its one of those technologies which are easy enough for anyone to use, but have a steep learning curve to use it properly

Comment: I think it's hard to do unit testing on visual characteristics like you describe in your edit. I've never had to do that for a react app, generally you build a component and worry about what it looks like, and partially worry about it's layout, and it's parent also handles part of it's layout because the layout can vary on different pages but the component itself should still visually look the same. Also if you don't want to keep refreshing the page you can use chrome dev tools to update the css and see how it looks, then when you pick something you like, apply it to your actual code

Comment: Yeah, this is my issue - I'm not specifically looking for unit testing here (it obviously helps for the functional stuff) - angular has that all well documented. The biggest problem I'm dealing with in regards to layout/styling is that the project has a single global (~6000 lines) css file for the whole webapp - with lots of `!important` overrides which causes a lot of inconsistencies and I'm admittedly not great with css so this requires a lot of trial and error

Comment: I have been using devtools for live adjustments and applying them to code but was wondering if there was a better way as this has a couple of annoyances. The first being angular CLI forcing a refresh whenever the source files are changed, and the second is to do with unexpected overrides in the global css which cause components to look fine in some places but not others depending on whether those selectors match. Guess that's still my best option at this point though. Thanks for your help. If you make that an answer I'm happy to mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's hard to do unit testing on visual characteristics like you describe in your edit. I've never had to do that for a react app, generally you build a component and worry about what it looks like, and partially worry about it's layout, and it's parent also handles part of it's layout because the layout can vary on different pages but the component itself should still visually look the same. Also if you don't want to keep refreshing the page you can use chrome dev tools to update the css and see how it looks, then when you pick something you like, apply it to your actual code

Answer (score 1):

Components are just classes. And they can be tested as such.

## More

- https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-test-basics

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm aware of this and to some degree it does help with mocking my components for testing, but it doesn't quite address the full scope of what I'm trying to achieve (more testing visual design elements). I have updated the question for clarity and will read through the docs again to see if I missed something about how to serve the component so I can render it in browser for design purposes